# Non-breaking breakpoint constantly triggers OnMouseMove event in Delphi XE3

Tags: delphi, debugging, breakpoints

I was trying to use a non-breaking breakpoint to log some values in a control's OnMouseMove event handler.  I noticed that the breakpoint was constantly being hit while the mouse was idle (not moving) over the control.

After a little investigation, I came to the conclusion that the breakpoint was responsible for this behaviour.  This problem can easily be reproduced with the following example.  When the breakpoint is enabled, the counter is constantly incremented while the mouse is over the form.  When the breakpoint is disabled, the counter increases only when the mouse moves over the form.

```
TForm1 = class(TForm)
  Edit1: TEdit; 
  procedure FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
public
  FCounter: Integer;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  Inc(FCounter);
  Edit1.Text := IntToStr(FCounter);
end;
```

I can find other ways of logging the information I need, however, I would like to know there are any workarounds that will let me use my original approach.

Comment: Related: https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=79514

Comment: Thanks for the link.  If I understand correctly, this is what's going on:  The IDE temporarily becomes the active window when the breakpoint is hit.  When the IDE is done its work, it makes my app the active window which results in a spurious WM_MOUSEMOVE message so the OS can do its thing (like ensure the correct pointer is used).  Unfortunately, that creates an infinite loop which means I have to use a different approach for logging.

Comment: Yes, I think that's exactly what is going on.